# how to check id is existed before insert to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 related table

one is **claim_item_category**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|    claim_item_id    | claim_item_name  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |  Transport       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |  Medical         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

second is **claim_list**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    claim_list_id    |  claim_item_id   |     Amount       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        1         |     20.50        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

User have a selector box to select **Claim Item**

```
<select name="claim_item_id" class="form-control" required="required" aria-required="true">
 <option value="" selected="SELECTED">...</option>
 <option value="1">Transport</option>
 <option value="2">Medical</option>
  </select>
```

IF they inspect the code change **option value to 3 which is not existed in claim_item_category table** and it will also save in to database and then output will be blank.

Its possible check the **claim_item_category - claim_item_id** is already existed then only save?

My insert sql query :

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO `claim_list`
                (`claim_item_id`,`Amount`) 
                VALUES 
                ('%d','%s');"
                ,$this->claim_category_id,$this->claim_amount);
```

**Update**

I have add foreign key with two table so if claim_item_id is not exited then cannot insert or update. **Problem Solved**, thank you

Comment: Use a `select` with `where` clause checking for particular `id` before `insert` statement to check if `id` exist.

Comment: There is no need to check first. Indeed, it's counter productive - and disappointing that none of the other respondents (so far) know that. You can simply run the INSERT. When the INSERT fails, you know the indexed id exists already. Alternatively, see INSERT... SELECT syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For example IF YOU HAVE 3 SELECTOR BOX.

```
    $id=[];
    if(isset($_POST['claim_item_id1']&& !empty(($_POST['claim_item_id1'])){

        $id[]=$_POST['claim_item_id1'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['claim_item_id2']&& !empty(($_POST['claim_item_id2'])){
        $id[]=$_POST['claim_item_id2'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['claim_item_id3']&& !empty(($_POST['claim_item_id3'])){
        $id[]=$_POST['claim_item_id3'];
    }

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");   
    foreach($id as $idnum){
      $result=$mysqli->query("select * from claim_item_category where claim_item_id = '".$idnum."'");
      $rows=$result->num_rows;
        if($rows >0){
          //insert your query here
        }
    }
```

If you have n number of selector boxes use n number of selector boxes

Comment: If 3 selector box are from different table?

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "databse");   

if(isset($_POST['claim_item_id1']&& !empty(($_POST['claim_item_id1'])){

    $id=$_POST['claim_item_id1'];
    $result=$mysqli->query("select * from claim_item_category1 where claim_item_id = '".$id."'");
    $rows=$result->num_rows;
    if($rows >0){
      //insert your query here
    }

}
if(isset($_POST['claim_item_id2']&& !empty(($_POST['claim_item_id2'])){
    $id=$_POST['claim_item_id2'];
    $result=$mysqli->query("select * from claim_item_category2 where claim_item_id = '".$id."'");
    $rows=$result->num_rows;
    if($rows >0){
      //insert your query here
    }

}
if(isset($_POST['claim_item_id3']&& !empty(($_POST['claim_item_id3'])){
    $id=$_POST['claim_item_id3'];
    $result=$mysqli->query("select * from claim_item_category3 where claim_item_id = '".$id."'");
    $rows=$result->num_rows;
    if($rows >0){
      //insert your query here
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = $mysqli-query("select count(claim_item_id) from claim_item_category where  claim_item_id = " . $_POST['claim_item_id'] . ");
if($data) {
sprintf("INSERT INTO `claim_list`
                (`claim_item_id`,`Amount`) 
                VALUES 
                ('%d','%s');"
                ,$this->claim_category_id,$this->claim_amount);
} else {
    echo 'Claim category not exist.';
}
```

Comment: What if someone else inserts data in between operation 1 and operation 2. This kind of solution is potentially disastrous.

Comment: Hi, I have more than one selector box so do you have any best pratice way to achieve it?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$id=$_POST['claim_item_id'];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$result=$mysqli-query("select * from claim_item_category where claim_item_id = '".$id."'");
$rows=$mysqli->num_rows;
if($rows >0){
//insert your query here
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have more than one selector box so do you have any best pratice way to achieve it?